Can't display timestamp retrieved from Firebase and display on ion-datetime
I'm retrieving a timestamp from firebase - no issues there
on my *.page.ts I have
public matchDate: Date;    


this.matchDate = this.currentMatchDetails.date;

when I console.log that I get it in the format "this.matchDate = 063844313400.000000000"
in my *.page.html I have
   <ion-datetime
         [(ngModel)]="matchDate"
         displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY HH:mm"
          pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY HH:mm"
          value="{{currentMatchDetails?.date}}">
        </ion-datetime>

However I get the warning
Unable to parse date string: Timestamp(seconds=1711818035, nanoseconds=129000000). Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime string.
and the datepicker defaults to today's date and time.
How (and where) to I convert my date to ISO 8601 datetime?
